Serialize the custom attributes along with class properties in C# on .NET?
I have a Person class with custom attribute over few properties, I want to serialize this class object using Newtonsoft JSON.NET features. My custom attribute should also get serialized into the JSON.
Do we have anything built-in in Newtonsoft JSON.NET for this?
public class Person
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
        
    [Encrypted(key="PersonalData")]
    public String Address { get; set; }

    [Encrypted(key="PersonalData")]
    public String Phone { get; set; }

    [Encrypted(key="PersonalData")]
    public String IdentityDetails{ get; set; }
}

When the JSON string gets exported through serialization, the applied custom attributes over the properties should also get exported as part of the JSON, so that by looking at the JSON data, we can identify that those property value are encrypted. So that other program where we are sending the JSON string can take the action accordingly for those property value, my class is not fixed, we can send any class JSON string to other program that is responsible to read the JSON and process that.

"I want while sterilization my custom attribute should also get sterilized in Json string." - what do you mean by that? How resulting JSON should look like?

It is not clear what you are looking for and it would help if you show us the expected serialized JSON output.
I assume you are going to end up having to write a custom JsonConverter as I don't think JsonProperty() is what you are looking for unless it is but that's not clear at this point.

@GuruStron there were typo, It's corrected now.

I don't think there is something like that. Its common practice to have multiple models for multiple purposes. So if you have a specific requirements how the serialized Person should look like create a model class that explicitly looks like you want it to be serialized and create a mapping between this Person class and the one for serialization to json.

I can see several ways to do this. BUT I'd actually discourage doing it in the first place. If you encrypt properties, then this fact should be part of the interface / contract and thus be known without having to mark the properties in the transferred data. For one: "is encrypted" is not enough info, anyway. The consumer would have to know how to decrypt, with what key etc etc do you want to serialize that information, too?

Defining attribute Encrypted with exactly defined parameters,
Writing custom JsonObjectContract
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonObjectContract.htm
Share Model class attribute and contract acroos all opponents Seems thet way you should go. BUT ENCRYPTION key at attribute made a blast on my brain :) DONT DO THAT !!! WHY? :)

the applied custom attributes over the properties should also get exported as part of the JSON, so that by looking at the JSON data, we can identify that those property value are encrypted. -- could you please [edit] your question to share a sample of your desired JSON for your Person class?  It's not obvious how the presence of an attribute would be included in a JSON object.  In XML one could include an attribute on the relevant element but JSON doesn't have attributes.

@Fildor,  it's just an example not the real class for my application.

@kanpinar, the key provided in attribute is not the actual key, it's an reference of key where the real value is stored. I will look into the your suggestion using JsonObjectContract

@dbc, that what I was looking for, is there any way to do that.
